# Calling Google App Engine (iAP Enabled) from Google Cloud Function within the same Project

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions

Context:

- Node Server in Google App Engine (GAE) that effectively houses a backend for a frontend that is also served by the same app engine instance

  - Hence why iAP is enabled (for selected web app users only)
  - Has various endpoints for the frontend to call via reverse-proxy (as I understand it's called)
- Google Cloud Function(GCF) within the same project that (funny enough) is actually being called by the node server to initiate the cloud function that then needs to call an endpoint within the GAE node server.

  - ....k wait I might've just found another way to solve the problem but I'll get to that at the end.
- I created a VPC Connector for GCF to access a VM instance that I created to talk to external networks. GAE (Flex) is able to do so natively. Not sure if this is relevant but wanted to throw it in the mix.

Short term solution:

- Since I need to call the GCF from the GAE node server first, I can just provide it with the relevant data as needed.

Long term solution:

- Ideally, the GCF should be called by any other services that might or might not have the data, so it would be ideal to have the GCF call out the GAE endpoint to get the data.

So far:

```
import urllib

import google.auth.transport.requests
import google.oauth2.id_token

req = urllib.request.Request('https://the-gcp-project-id.appspot.com/api/theEndpoint')

auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
id_token = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(auth_req, 'https://appengine.googleapis.com')

log.info("Authorization: " + f"Bearer {id_token}")
# req.add_header("Authorization", f"Bearer {id_token}")
# response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

# # return response.read()
# log.info(response.read())
import requests as reqs
response = reqs.post('https://the-gcp-project-id.appspot.com/theEndpoint', json={'test':'123'}, headers={"Authorization" : f"Bearer {id_token}"})
log.info(response)
```

This doesn't seem to actually trigger the endpoint though. As far as I know the service account for the cloud function should have the same permissions as the app engine service account.
Can anyone point me in the right direction on this?

Comment: Do you have a question? Is there something wrong with what you have now?  Please edit the question to be clear what you need help with and what's not working the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson updated

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Are you seeing any errors?  Any logging to explain what actually happened?  How can this be reproduced?